# Как изменить формат отображения даты в datePciker mui в реакте

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, mui

я использую datePicker из mui
вот код

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale={ru}>
    <DatePicker
      maxDate={dateBy || defaultDate}
      defaultValue={defaultDate}
      onChange={newVal => {
        // timestamp на начало дня
        if (setStartDate) {
          sessionStorage.setItem('since', `${+newVal}`);

          setStartDate(+newVal);
        }
        if (setEndDate) {
          sessionStorage.setItem('till', `${+newVal}`);

          setEndDate(+newVal);
        }
      }}
      label={label}
      componentsProps={{
        textField: {
          size: 'small',
        },
      }}
      sx={{ ml: 0.5, flexGrow: 0.5, mt: 0.2, maxWidth: 230 }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

я получаю формат даты что-то типа 04.05.2023
а хотелось бы получать такой формат 04 мая 2023, подскжаите можно ли это как-то реализовать? Пробовал свойства format, view, но так и не получил желаемого?

Comment: указать [кастомный формат](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#custom-formats) в соответствии с этой [таблицей](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/format)